# Can i use SUMPRODUCT to ignore blank cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My spreadsheet has a list of names (some are repeated) in column A, a list of numbers stored in a string in column B, and column C uses a formula to get the first number of the string in column B. In column E have created a list of the unique names from column A, in column F a number of times they appear in the data list and in column G i then want to fetch the corresponding number data from column C each time it appears in the list to calculate average numbers.

I have tried this

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))=$E4)*($C$2:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C))))/$F4`

The problem i have is that in the list of data some of the cells in column C are blank so i am getting a `#VALUE` error.

Here is a screenshot of what i am trying:

[image: new output]

Is there anyway to tell `SUMPRODUCT` to skip the rows where there is no number data?

Obviously this is just an example and my actual spreadsheet is a little more complicated, there are thousands of rows of data and the names are repeated many times over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty cells are not your problem. It would just be accepted in a formula like yours. Unfortunately the problem is because you have gaps, `COUNTA` will return a range that's not equal to column A > `COUNTA` in column A will return 15, whereas `COUNTA` in column C will return 11. Unequal ranges will return `#VALUE`

In this specific case your issue is resolved through:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))=$E4)*($C$1:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($A:$A))))/$F4
```

---

[image]

Comment: I assumed that could be the problem and i tried that but it still get a `#VALUE` error

Comment: As per my screenshot, you can see that the formula is not the problem at hand here. It must be your data. Your numbers don't actually look like formatted numbers. Makes sure they are formatted as numbers and get rid of leading/trailling spaces. @MA84

Comment: Ok, ill sort my data out !!

Comment: I am struggling a little, its definitely the format throwing up the problem but i am formatting the cells as `number` but it excel does not want to seem to format them as a number

Comment: Can you upload a file with a piec of your data? I'll tell you what the problem is then. It's probably unseen characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200394/discussion-between-ma84-and-jvdv).

Comment: @MA84, here is the formula to put in `AC2` > `=IF(Z2<>"",TRIM(LEFT($Z2,FIND(";",$Z2&";")-1))*1,0)` and drag that down.

Comment: In your solution $C$2:INDEX  should be $C$1:INDEX.

That could be why it wasnt working for him

Comment: @LafaMan, well spotted =). However, the problem was somewhere else and has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In G4, copied down :

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,$E4,$C:$C)/$F4
```

Edit : SUMIF() can use whole column reference of which bounded on used range only, and  can avoid to use dynamic range.